Printing for Debugging Purposes in Supabase SQL Editor
I'm relatively new to both PL/pgSQL and Supabase, and I'm currently working on debugging my code within the Supabase SQL editor. I'd like to know how I can print or similiar function in the SQL editor specifically for debugging purposes. Could someone provide suggestions or best practices for achieving this?
Here's a simple example function I've tried:
create or replace function print_example ()
  returns text language plpgsql as $$
begin
    raise notice '%', 'hello world';
    return '';
end;
$$;

select
  print_example ();

I can't seem to locate where the result is displayed.

It's doesn't show in the result.

I can't find it in pg log.

You can use raise log instead, which will show up in the logs.
